# Redirect result to other process on command line

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I am trying to change pooling settings by getting list of pools starting with 'abc' and then change parameters using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start. In this case change it to 32 bits.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Arguments = "list apppool /name:$=\"*abc*\" /xml | c:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd set apppool /in /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true",
            FileName = "appcmd.exe",
            WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + @"\system32\inetsrv\",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        });

    }
}
```

The problem I am having is with piping inside arguments. I am not too sure if this is allowed and what syntactically should look like. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it would be easier if the output of the first command is read into current process and then this is written into the second command. Like that:

```
Process first = new Process();
first.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
first.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
first.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd";
first.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + @"\system32\inetsrv\";
first.StartInfo.Arguments = "list apppool /name:$=\"*abc*\" /xml";
first.Start();
string output = first.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
first.WaitForExit();

// now put into the second
Process second = new Process();
second.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe";
second.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + @"\system32\inetsrv\";
second.StartInfo.Arguments = "set apppool /in /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true";
second.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
second.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
second.Start();
second.StandardInput.Write(output);
second.StandardInput.Close();
second.WaitForExit();
```